# How to handle large pointer structures

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I writing an application that pushes data over an external service to some server. There is a defined structure that I have to use for this, and it looks like this:

```
class A {
    B *b; // Another class built the same principle
    C *c; // And another one
    ...
};
```

and it somewhere boils down to

```
class XY {
    double *some_val;
    std::string *another_val;
    ...
};
```

The problem I am facing is that I am only dealing with pointers of pointers of pointers if you will, and I haven't figured out yet what would be the best way of dealing with these structures.

I could handle memory management myself with `new` and `delete`, but I would have to do massive cleanup afterwards and chances that I forget to clean something up and my program leaks are too high in my opinion.

I could declare the classes locally and fill them up that way, but I would have to declare every variable beforehand then, so I have to analyze the class hierachy before I can do anything and after that it will still get really messy.

Smart pointers came in my mind as well, but since they are basically a class wrapping a pointer I would have to declare them beforehand as well, the advantages over the previous method seem to be small.

**Does anyone know a smart and, most of all, readable/maintainable method to handle these massive pointer structures?**

*Update:*

If anyone runs into the same problem, this is my approach now (though I still think it's messy!):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

class A {
    B *b_;
    double *d_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<boost::any> vp;

    // Create instance of A
    vp.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<A>(new A));
    A *a = boost::any_cast<boost::shared_ptr<A> >(vp.back()).get();

    // Create instance of B in A
    vp.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<B>(new B));
    a->b_ = boost::any_cast<boost::shared_ptr<B> >(vp.back()).get();

    // etc.

    return 0;
}
```

*Update 2:*

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

typedef std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<void> > MemoryManager;

template <class T> T* create_managed(T *ptr, MemoryManager &memorymanager) {
    memorymanager.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<T>(ptr));
    return boost::static_pointer_cast<T>(memorymanager.back()).get();
}

int main() {
    MemoryManager mm;
    A *a = create_managed(new A, mm);
    a->b_ = create_managed(new B, mm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `boost::any`, you might want to use `shared_ptr<void>`.

Comment: @Mankarse Thanks a lot, that is really awesome. I updated my question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [smart pointers](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html), they have a big advantage:

> To be smarter than regular pointers, smart pointers need to do things that regular pointers don't. What could these things be? Probably the most common bugs in C++ (and C) are related to pointers and memory management: dangling pointers, memory leaks, allocation failures and other joys. Having a smart pointer take care of these things and can save a lot of aspirin...

Comment: I have considered smartpointers and explained my reasons why I think they do not help here. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @nijansen: The difference is that with smart pointers, the automatically-generated destructors for your classes destroy the smart pointers which in turn automatically free the objects pointed to when they become unreferenced.

Comment: Yes, I do understand how smart pointers work; my point is - smart pointers clean themselves up when they run out of scope, so I would have to declare every smart pointer beforehand and still have a massive and unreadable block of smart pointers (getting even messier with arrays of arrays of smart pointers...) and I don't see the advantage over declaring an instance of the class locally.

Comment: What about having a std::vector as a member of your main class to store all these pointers?

Comment: I tried to construct this vector you are suggesting. I am using `boost::shared_ptr`, but I cannot do something like `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<> >` - it requires a template parameter. `boost::any` could work, but then I'll have lots of working around again. I really like your idea though, can I do it with just one vector, or do I have to construct a vector for each class?

Comment: I believe you can use 1 `std::vector` with `boost::any`.

Answer (score 1):

Smart pointers is what you need. There are a lot of their implementation, or you can write your own. Using them in proper way you don't have to care about deleting your classes.